# Gluon mobile arabic in setText

Tags: java, arabic, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to write some arabic letters in a Label but:

When using fxml files it works great with no problems at all

When using `Label.setText` it doesn't work and just puts some "?" insted of the text I wanted

I tried changing the font but it's not working

Comment: Are you sure that any of the font you tried support arabic? Is your input text properly encoded?

Comment: Yes I even don't set fonts in my fxml files, I tried using Arial just for testing but no luck. And I just write direct Arabic I don't use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Maybe your computer uses some code page and the rest of your program expect UTF-8?

Comment: I don't know but In my normal javafx application I do the same thing and it works great, It's just the gluon mobile/javafxports application.

Comment: I tried using unicode characters and it worked but I wanted to know why it doesn't work with gluon mobile but works in normal javafx. Edit: I also don't want to change all my code to use unicode characters because it will take alot of time